# Right click context menu on Windows executing Python scripts

Tags: python, windows, registry

I want to start a python script using the Windows Explorer's right-click context menu.
These are my registry entries to achieve that:

---

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\CleanDesktop - Add to persistent files]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\CleanDesktop - Add to persistent files\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\Admin\\PycharmProjects\\clean_desktop\\wescript.py\" %1"
```

---

I also edited the environment variables so that if I simply run the command: 
"C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\clean_desktop\wescript.py" "some_argument" in cmd it works just fine. 
I tested it with a simple .exe file compiled from an c program

---

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\CleanDesktop - Add to persistent files\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\Admin\\PycharmProjects\\clean_desktop\\ctest.exe\" %1"
```

---

And it works just fine. But if I try the same with a .py file Windows states that: *This Application cannot be opened on this PC* 
Is there a way to achieve what I want without the need of making an .exe file out of the .py file ?

Comment: Python files are not executable. Try with `C:\Path\To\python.exe C:\Path\To\script.py %1`

Comment: @zvone Ok that worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using `HKCR` to define keys is generally incorrect. Decide whether you want to define this for all users in `HKLM\Software\Classes` or the current user in `HKCU\Software\Classes`. If you use `HKCR`, then if the `HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\CleanDesktop - Add to persistent files\command` key already exists, then your .reg file will implicitly add the default value for the current user instead of for all users. Unlikely? Maybe in your case. But it's a bad habit to develop. `HKCR` is only meant for *reading*.